# Access Azure cost management API data from Azure Data Factory using managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

I have a [data factory v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) with managed identity automatically assigned to it (object id + tenant id). I also have a resource accessible through `Azure's` [Cost Management REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/)

What I'd like to do is try to create `REST` [linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services) and authenticate to the `API` using the automatically generated managed identity.

So, for that purpose in `Azure Portal -> Cost/billing resource -> IAM` I have given two roles to my `ADF` managed identity: `Billing Reader` and `Cost Management Reader`.

But when I invoke the linked service configured like this:

[image]

And configured in the [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) Sink like this:

[image]

I get the following error:

[image]

I am really confused with this message and I don't really understand it is supposed to mean:

Cost management data is unavailable for subscription xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. The offer `MS-AZR-xxxxx` is not supported.

Comment: The problem may be that your subscription is not concerned by cost management (such as the free or educational accounts). Microsoft maintains a list of supported offers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/understand-cost-mgt-data